# WhereIN from model function laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

- Hi there, please i try to make a small application in laravel, and i get same issues with **hasMany** relation-ship :
  I get **Client** model and this model have **multi** **affiliate**
  This is code:

  ```
  class Client extends Model
  {

      public function affiliates()
      {
          return $this->hasMany('App\Client');
      }
  ```

  .....

And the problem is :

I try to select the project list for a specifique  client and his affiliate together

```
$filiale_client_ids = DB::table('clients')
                    ->where('client_id',$request->get('client_id'))
                    ->select('id')
                    ->get();


$projects = Project::withTrashed()
        ->where('client_id',$request->get('client_id'))
        ->whereIn('client_id', $filiale_client_ids);
```

And it always doesn't make sense, Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough!! What do you want to achieve?

Comment: add a minimal example of your tables please

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem, and i share my solution:

```
$filiale_client_ids= Client::find($request->get('client_id'))->affiliates->pluck('id');

        $project = Project::withTrashed()
        ->where('client_id',$request->get('client_id'))
        ->orWhereIn('client_id', $filiale_client_ids)
        ->get();
```